# Serve static files from memory in Scotty webapp

Tags: haskell, scotty

For ease of app relocation I would like to serve static files from memory instead of disk in my Scotty application. I'm currently using [`wai-middleware-static`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-middleware-static) to serve files from disk but I see that there is a [`wai-app-static`](https://www.stackage.org/package/wai-app-static) that could do it, but it is not in the form of a `Middleware`.

Can I turn the `wai-app-static` `Application` into a `Middleware` or is there another package I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find what I was looking for so I made my own: https://github.com/adamse/wai-middleware-static-embedded based on `wai-middleware-static`.

It provides a function

```
static :: [(FilePath, ByteString)] -> Middleware
```

which serves a file if it is in the supplied list.

Answer (score 1):

[`Middleware`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-3.0.4.0/docs/Network-Wai.html#t:Middleware) has the type `Application -> Application`. So if you
want to turn `someApplication` into `Middleware`, a way you could do
it is:

```
staticMiddleware :: Middleware
staticMiddleware = \app -> someApplication
```

You throw away an argument that is an `Application` and return the
application you want, and now you have `Middleware`!

Probably not very useful `Middleware`. You may want to look at the
request to figure out how to handle it? Like, some requests are going
to be handled by this static server middleware, and others are going
to be handled your regular server?

Maybe you could do something like this:

```
someMiddleware :: Middleware
someMiddleware = \app -> branchingApp

branchingApp :: Application
branchingApp req functionReqToRecieved =
  if iWantToStaticServeThis req
  then staticApp req functionReqToRecieved
  else dynamicApp req functionReqToRecieved
```

This is terrible code so please don't copy but I hope it gets the idea across?

An [`Application`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-3.0.4.0/docs/Network-Wai.html#t:Application) is a function: `Request -> (Response -> IO
ResponseReceived) -> IO ResponseReceived`.  I want to say how to use
that first argument (the request). So, instead of saying this
`Middleware` returns this predefined application, I'm constructing my
own `Application`, that just takes a look at the `Request` and decides
which `Application` should handle it. Then it passes the arguments
back to the `Application`.

There might be a helper function somewhere that does this for you,
too, but I'm not sure.

Comment: (I saw you already figured out an answer but I had this in draft so I posted anyway in case it's helpful to someone in the future.)

Comment: Thank you, this gave me some things to think about! :)